# validationEngine js plugin does not prevent form with custom submit event to be sent

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I am using validationEngine to validate a form before it is sent;

**plug-in**

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

It works fine except when I write my on submit handle to a form.

For instance

```
<form id="form" action="controller/action" method="post"></form>

$('#form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        success: function (response) {
            success(response);
        }
    });
});
```

the validation is performed but the form is posted anyway.
I have also tried to get the returned value with:

```
alert($("#formUpdStoringSettings").validationEngine('validate'));
```

and it always return true for forms and false for fields wich means that the validation is ok.

Is there any workaround for that as long as I need to have my custom submit event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out validationEngne aims to validate form during the interaction the user with the form. It is not intended to validate on submit event.

I had to create my own validation functions.